# How to add signature timestamp while signing a PDF?

Tags: pdfbox, digital-signature

I am able to add digital signatures to PDF using external trust service providers and `PDFBox` library. Right now my system clock is being used for signature timestamp.

I checked `PDFBox` samples, it has examples for Document Timestamps which is adding extra timestamp signatures.
How can I add the timestamp using external trust sources with my current signature?

Also, what updates are required in signature dictionary and DSS/DTS dictionary after adding timestamp?

Comment: The examples do use an external source. Which example did you use?

Comment: this example with some required modification: https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateSignature.java

Comment: That code does add a timestamp and sign at the same time. You just need to have such a service. Re DSS etc, thats in the validation package. If your question is about adding a timestamp only, that's in CreateSignedTimeStamp.java . If your question is about updateing a signature with a timestamp, that's in ValidationTimeStamp.java .